# Efficient way to order a Java list based on another list

Tags: java, list, sorting, java-11

I have 2 lists for my application. ListA - {id, address, name} ListB - {address}

ListB is sorted based on user input.

```
ListA - {{1, {id:1, street:"abc"}, personA},
{2, {id:2, street:"def"}, personB},
{3, {id:3, street:"ghi"}, personC},
{4, {id:4, street:"jk"}, personD}}

ListB - {
{id:3, street:"ghi"},
{id:2, street:"def"}
{id:4, street:"jk"},
{id:1, street:"abc"}
}

RESULT After LISTA is sorted
LISTA - {{3, {id:3, street:"ghi"}, personC},
{2, {id:2, street:"def"}, personB},
{4, {id:4, street:"jk"}, personD}},
{1, {id:1, street:"abc"}, personA},
```

I can do

```
List<> orderedList = new arraylist()<>;
ListB.forEach(address -> {
 orderedList.add(ListA.stream.filter(pers -> pers.getAddress.equals(address)).findFirst().get());
}
```

Is there more efficient way to do so?

Comment: Instead of find an *efficient way to sort*, you can just use a different data structure. This all wouldn't be a question if you used a `Map<id, {your object}>` for `ListA` (instead of a `List<{your object}>`).

Comment: The list is returned by spring data jpa. So I cannot change the list A but then convert it from the list to a map. but then not sure if it will be different then what i did to order.

Comment: Your pseudo code is producing a list in `ListB`’s order. This doesn’t change when you convert `ListA` to a `Map` first, followed by streaming over `ListB` and looking up the objects in the map.